# ImportError: No module named admin.js.compress,,,, etc

Tags: python, django

I am trying to debug a django project code but when i run it shows an error like:

```
ERROR: Module: admin.js.compress could not be imported (file: C:/Users/admin/workspace/Project/admin/js/compress.py)
```

Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong.. ?

Full Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Softwares\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.‌​1.2012100913\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", 
line 432, in __get_module_from_str mod = __import__(modname) ImportError: No module named build.psycopg2.doc.src.conf 
ERROR: Module: build.psycopg2.doc.src.conf could not be imported (file: C:/Users/admin/workspace/Project/build/psycopg2/doc/src/conf.py)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback and the code when you invoke compress.py? And are you sure you have an __ init __.py in the js folder?

Comment: yes i have init.py in the folder.. and here is the traceback code which i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Softwares\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 432, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
ImportError: No module named build.psycopg2.doc.src.conf
ERROR: Module: build.psycopg2.doc.src.conf could not be imported (file: C:/Users/admin/workspace/Project/build/psycopg2/doc/src/conf.py).

Comment: Please paste the traceback in a pastebin or in a gist for better lecture :D

Comment: I think it is simply that the file build/psycopg1/doc/src/conf.py contains errors. Have you tried to import it from the shell using :

    from build.psycopg2.doc.src import conf ?

You will have more error information about the issue.